# Calculating flux through a surface

Tags: integration

Calculate the flux of the filed:

$$F(x,y,z)=(3x-2y+z, 2x+3y-z, x-3y+z)$$

through the surface:

$$S: |3x-2y+z|+|2x+3y-z|+|x-3y+z|=1$$

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

What you call  "surface" is the boundary of an " oblique" octahedron $O$: Introduce new coordinates $(u,v,w)$ by means of
$$u:=3x-2y+z, \quad v:=2x+3y-z, \quad w:=x-3y+z\ .\tag{1}$$
In terms of $(u,v,w)$ the "surface" $S$ appears as $|u|+|v|+|w|=1$, which is the boundary of the "virtual" octahedron $\hat O:\ |u|+|v|+|w|\leq1$ in $(u,v,w)$-space.

Note that ${\rm div}(F)\equiv7$. Therefore, assuming outward orientation of $S$, the requested flux is by Gauss' theorem equal to $7$ times the $(x,y,z)$-volume of $O$. Therefore it remains to compute this volume.

The formulae $(1)$ define a linear map $T:\>(x,y,z)\mapsto(u,v,w)$ which maps $O$ onto $\hat O$. One computes $|\det T|=3$, which implies that $T$ multiplies volumes by $3$. Now $\hat O$ can be viewed as double pyramid (with height $1$ each)  over a square of area $2$; so  ${\rm vol}(\hat O)=2\cdot{1\over3}\cdot 2\cdot1$. It follows that ${\rm vol}(O)={1\over3}{\rm vol}(\hat O)={4\over9}$.

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't understand yet how to compute the volume of$$O$$.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you very much!